# iOS 11 devices fail to access nginx HTTPS site secured with LetsEncrypt (Protocol error)

Tags: docker, nginx, https, ios11, lets-encrypt

Since a couple of days, users that just updated to iOS 11 cannot access my website.
It's hosted via a nginx reverse proxy that is using LetsEncrypt to provide SSL.

The client experience is, that if you click a link, usually the safari window just disappears or shows a generic error.

Using the debugger, there's an error: **[Error[ Failed to load resource: The operation couldn't be completed. Protocol Error**

This only happens with iOS devices since the update to iOS 11.

My Server is running on DigitalOcean with the docker image [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy).

Comment: This happens to Apache as well.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I actually found the issue to be related to an improper implementation of HTTP2 in iOS11.

This post shed some light on the situation:
http://www.essential.exchange/2017/09/18/ios-11-about-to-release-things-to-be-aware-of/

The *jwilder/nginx-proxy* docker image is using **http2** by default and as far as I can see you can't change that either.

No, to solve the issue, remove the *http2* keyword in your server configuration for now.

**This:**

```
server {
  listen x.x.x.x:443 ssl http2;
  server_name xxxx;
  [...]
}
```

**Becomes:**

```
server {
  listen x.x.x.x:443 ssl;
  server_name xxxx;
  [...]
}
```

If you're running *jwilder/nginx-proxy* you will have to change */app/nginx.tmpl* too, otherwise, the config file will be rewritten at one point.

Hope this answer helps some people struggling with the same problem.
If you find another solution to fix this, please add it below. I haven't had too much time to look for solutions as it took me forever to find this one.

Comment: This is an insidious and difficult problem to diagnose, particularly for people that use Windows machines and don't have a Mac handy.  It is not just a Docker problem; it is an iOS problem when interacting with HTTP/2 servers using an SSL certificate.  The symptoms, more generally, are that iOS browsers of all types (Safari, Chrome) silently fail to load a web page, with no error message other than that it failed to load.  The only way to detect the problem is to use Web Inspector in Safari (good luck if you don't have a Mac).

Comment: It's also not limited to Nginx; in Apache, the solution in Apache is to disable HTTP/2 in this way:

# Enable HTTP/2 by default
#
# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#protocols

#<IfModule mod_http2.c>
#    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
#</IfModule>